# How to achieve this button-border effect with CSS? (image included)

Tags: css

[image]

Right now, our mockups / live demo use images to achieve this effect (including button text).  This is less than desirable for all of the standard reasons.  I can get everything working except that pesky outer border.  I'd really like to not add markup to my document just to have that.

I've got my test code on jsfiddle, although it doesn't work as well there as it does on my local machine:  http://jsfiddle.net/Axtjm/

tldr: how to add inset border like that and keep rounded corners without extra markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inset box-shadow. If you're already using a box-shadow on your buttons, remember that you can stack box-shadows by using commas to separate each.

```
button {
 border: 1px solid #369;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff, 1px 1px 2px #000;
}
```

The above is just an example; replace the values with your own if necessary. If you want a bolder inset shadow, you can also stack two insets of the same value to achieve that.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Axtjm/5/

Answer (score 5):

As unintuitive as this sounds, don't use `outline` for outlines. Use `box-shadow` with a `1px` spread:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #049ED9;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Axtjm/4/**

Comment: @ZackMacomber: The only thing that's missing in IE9 for me is the font, and I think that's because Century Gothic isn't installed on my machine.

Comment: @recursive - sorry...forgot to mention version...IE 8

Comment: @Blender, good work, but I am wonder how did you know the type of font used in the image ?

Comment: @Zack Macomber- box-shadow is css3 is not supported in IE8 an earlier versions.

Comment: @Alaa: it's named in the fiddle in the OP

Comment: I really appreciate that you used my original markup.  Have an upvote

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to add the extra container element and give each a border.

But the challenge is to do it without the border. Some ideas:

- use a border and then a very thin box-shadow.
- use the border style attribute AND the outline style attribute

(both dependent on the browser supporting them)

Quick JSBIN demo: http://jsbin.com/irabul

Comment: I was thinking the same. If it's possible without doing this, you'll find it here: http://css3button.net/showcase/

Answer (score 1):

it is using border-radius property of CSS3
and simple CSS border techniques,

some of the border property,

```
solid   Specifies a solid border  
double  Specifies a double border  
groove  Specifies a 3D grooved border. The effect depends on the border-color value  
ridge   Specifies a 3D ridged border. The effect depends on the border-color value  
inset   Specifies a 3D inset border. The effect depends on the border-color value  
outset  Specifies a 3D outset border. The effect depends on the border-color value  
inherit     Specifies that the border style should be inherited from the parent element
```

and here is the border-radius in detail,

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/